# notification bar in libgdx game

Tags: android, libgdx

I want to create game using Libgdx engine. It's create by default **FULLSCREEN** game without notification bar.
Can i create game **with** notification bar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Android starter:

```
public class MainActivity extends AndroidApplication {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        cfg.hideStatusBar = false;
        initialize(new MainClass(), cfg);
    }
}
```

The important line here being **cfg.hideStatusBar = false;**

Hope that helps

**EDIT**

Ok so I've done a bit of research on the subject and it turns out it's pretty easy. I looked on the [libgdx wiki page for adding admob ads](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/AdMobInLibgdx). Follow all the steps except adding the ads!

Below is modified code for setting up a non-fullscreen android app:

```
public class MainActivity extends AndroidApplication {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        layout.addView(initializeForView(new MainClass(), false));
        setContentView(layout);
    }
}
```

You can add all the layout parameters you want very easily by googleing "RelativeLayout layoutParams". Hope this helps. Please mark the question as answered.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. HideStatusBar is for android 4.x ... Can i show status bar on devices with 2.3 android or less?

Answer (score 7):

Since I am not (yet) allowed to comment I will make it an answer. Basically everything said by LiamJPeters helps, except you have set up the project recently from scratch with one of the newer libgdx nightlies, then there will also be a **"res/values/styles.xml"** which is referenced in the **manifest**.

I had to change two settings there (in addition to everything written by LiamJPeters) to make it finally show the notification bar and the window title:

```
<resources>
    <style name="GdxTheme" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: only with these configurations worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I run into a confusion here and couldn't make it work for a while on Android Lollipop. I had to actually merge all the code provided here in the answers, to make my app show status bar.

So the final working code for me looks like this:

Java part - combining relative layout and hideStatusBar config (thanks to LiamJPeters)

```
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();

    config.hideStatusBar = false;

    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    layout.addView(initializeForView(new MyAndroidApp(), config));
    setContentView(layout);
}
```

And styles.xml part - windowFullscreen to false (thanks to Bernrd K.)

```
<resources>
    <style name="GdxTheme" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Note: windowNoTitle has nothing to do with status bar itself. Depends what you need, but the xml above shows the status bar only, no titles.